# Are highly controversial posts subject to deletion?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I had posted an answer to a question some time ago. The answer was highly controversial:

[image]

This answer sat dormant for quite some time until it was recently deleted. This was completely inexplicable considering that the comments indicated that many agreed with me and the answer did get 10 upvotes.

I immediately undeleted the question. (After all, I had a link to it in my profile. Nobody likes dead links.)

My question is "Why are answers being deleted *just because they're controversial?*"

Comment: I challenge your assertion that mods shouldn't ["delete an answer with 6 upvotes and multiple comments agreeing with it."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687827/what-version-of-internet-explorer-ie-should-my-web-app-support/2688083#2688083)  Many worthless answers have received upvotes and agreement. That said, I agree that this answer didn't warrant deletion. Who deleted it?

Comment: @Michael: [Will](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will)

Comment: Who said it was deleted just because it was controversial? On the other hand, seems like when a question is deleted, the reason ought to be stated.

Comment: @LarsH: That's a very good point.

Comment: Of course many agree with you, lots of people hate IE. That doesn't mean your answer wasn't rather obviously offensive; I would've flagged it if I'd seen it and I hate IE with the fire of a thousand suns

Answer (score 3):

Probably shouldn't have been deleted. But "joke" answer (your words) != controversial. Is there any reason that answer should exist?

Comment: Because virtually every web developer holds that viewpoint.

Comment: @George: I doubt that. Few like older versions. Later ones, not so much.

Comment: @Michael: [About 7,450,000 results](http://www.google.ca/search?q=hate+ie&sourceid=mozilla-search&start=0&start=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official).

Comment: @Michael Man's got a point.

Comment: @George: Cool! [Here's 6,080,000 results](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=i+hate+pie&qscrl=1).

Comment: [46,000,000 results.](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=axt&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&q=hate+summer&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) Proves that google results can't prove anything. (Ironic) (@Geo)

Comment: http://www.sucks-rocks.com/

Comment: Also, [21 million results for 'I love Internet Explorer'](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=17259,23756,24692,24878,24879,25217,25983,26511,26541,26561&sugexp=ldymls&tok=3B1JO6JZLrSttq0xSyxTIw&xhr=t&q=i+love+internet+explorer&cp=16&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=&oq=i+love+internet+&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=1de331493393b8ab) (@geo)

Comment: [This](http://tech.blorge.com/Structure:%20/2007/06/18/top-10-reasons-to-love-internet-explorer/) post was one of the funiest I ever read regarding IE... it's satirical.

Comment: [This](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=0) shows that IE is still unfortunately in widespread use.

Comment: Satirical? Could never have guessed, @George.

Comment: The point is that 21 m+ results for "love IE" != 21 m+ people liking IE.

Comment: No, the point is, I *love* pie, and I don't understand how anyone could hate it. Well, except for lemon meringue, that's just gross. And Firefox with its memory leaks, and Chrome compatibility issues, and...

Comment: @Michael: I hate lemon pie too. But Chrome is fast, CSS3-compliant, and stable. Tell me IE is any of those.

Comment: @George: oh, I don't mind lemon, it's the meringue I can't abide. Everything else in these comments is irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Lemon Meringue pie is fantastic. You just have to cook the meringue slow enough that it gets crisp instead of foamy / rubbery.